# Gulp BabelJs compile issue wrong order

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I am facing an issue related to compiling `ES6` scripts by using gulp babel. My project consists of maybe 40 - 50 different `ES6` files (one `class` per file). At the moment, the compile process relies on a maintained ordered list of these .js files to guarantee a correct compilation and output order.

In the very past I tried to let the `babel` plugin compile these files in its own order. Unfortunately the result were runtime errors due to missing declared classes (affected by wrong compilation order).

My question is now: Is there any way to guarantee the correct compilation order automatically instead of manually maintaining this list?
 If not, is there any ES6 compiler which does guarantee a correct compilation order automatically?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: well, babel itself should do that when analyzing your file dependencies. I would guess the problem comes from gulp-babel.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to declare packages and import them such as I would in java? At the moment I do not have any package declarations (and thus no imports). Could that be the reason why babel fails compiling in the correct order?

Comment: Well yes... You need use import/export. How can it get the dependencies if you don't specify where to get them?

Comment: Okay thank you! As far as I can see, this feature is currently not supported by each browser / device?  :(

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: It's going to be taken care of by babel.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give it a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is, that babel doesn't resolve your dependencies.

For example:

```
// ComponentA.js
import AbstractComponent from './AbstractComponent';
class ComponentA extends AbstractComponent { ... }

// AbstractComponent.js
class AbstractComponent { ... }
export default AbstractComponent;

// gulpfile.js
gulp.task('js', function () {
return gulp.src(['./resources/javascript/ComponentA.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(babel({ presets: ['@babel/env']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});
```

Issue here is, that babel can't find it's parent class, because it's not defined before ComponentA Class. I've same issue and no solution for that.

E.g. React you are able to import from classes and compile them to es5 and everything is fine...